# Solving $\frac{dy}{d\theta} + y \cos \theta = \frac{1}{2} \sin 2\theta$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry, substitution, initial-value-problems

> Solve 
>   $$\frac{dy}{d\theta} + y \cos \theta = \frac{1}{2} \sin 2\theta$$ with $y(\pi/2) = 4$.

I couldn't think of any useful substitution, so I tried simplifying this DE, but didn't get anywhere. Any ideas on the best way to approach this problem?

Comment: After that notice the cosine on both sides and take it as motivation to consider $(y-\sin x)$. Then $(y-\sin(x))'+(y-\sin x)\cos x=-\cos(x)$. Again factor out $\cos x$ to get $ (y-\sin(x)+1)'+(y-\sin x+1)\cos x=0$ which now is separable.

Answer (score 2):

$$y'+ y \cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{2} \sin(2\theta)$$
Multiply by integrating factor*** $\mu(\theta)=e^{\sin(\theta)}$
$$y'e^{\sin(\theta)}+ y e^{\sin(\theta)}\cos(\theta) = \frac{1}{2}e^{\sin(\theta)} \sin(2\theta)$$

$$(ye^{\sin(\theta)})' =e^{\sin(\theta)} \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)$$
Integrate
$$ye^{\sin(\theta)} =\int e^{\sin(\theta)} \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)d\theta$$
Substitute $u=\sin(\theta)$
$$ye^{\sin(\theta)} =\int e^uudu$$
$$ye^{\sin(\theta)} = e^uu-e^u+K$$
$$y= \sin(\theta)-1+Ke^{-\sin(\theta)} $$
Apply the initial condition

---

*** there is a formula for the integrating factor for an equation $y′+p(x)y=q(x)$ the integrating factor is   $\mu=e^{\int p(x)dx}$

Comment: how did you know what the integrating factor was?

Comment: Here by inspection but there is a formula for the integrating factor for an equation $y'+p(x)y=q(x)$ the integrating factor is $\mu =e^{\int p(x)dx}$ @sam

Comment: @sam I added some lines for the integrating factor I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

$$y'+y\cos(\theta)=\frac12\sin(2\theta)=\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) \tag 1$$

HINT :

Alternative method without talking of integrating factor :

First solve the associated homogeneous equation (which is separable)
$$y_h'+y_hcos(\theta)=0$$`
$$y_h=Ce^{-\sin(\theta)}$$
Then change of function (variation of parameter : replace the constant $C$ by a function)
$$y(\theta)=C(\theta)e^{-\sin(\theta)}$$
$$y'=C'(\theta)e^{-\sin(\theta)}-C\cos(\theta)e^{-\sin(\theta)}$$
Putting them into Eq.$(1)$ leads to a first order linear and separable ODE easy to solve for $C(\theta)$.

In fact, this is equivalent to the integrating factor method, but without frighten with the search of an integrating factor when one doesn't remember the formula to find it.